# How to make all commits after one commit into another branch?

Tags: git

My current branches look like:

```
hash01--hash02--hash03--hash04--hash05--hash06--hash07 (master)
        |
        |-hash12-hash13-hash14-hashX-hash20-hash21-hash22-hash23-hash24 (develop)
```

I want to make(merge/cherry-pick/whatever) commits after `hashX` to `master`

How can I do that? This is a simplified example, there are many many commits here.

Comment: Please show us what your final branch looks like.

Comment: `git checkout master` `git cherry-pick hashX..develop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `git rebase --onto` is for.

First checkout `develop`, then `git rebase --onto master hashX`. `hashX` should be the last commit that you *don't* want brought over to master.

Comment: You're missing a step.  After your answer, the OP needs to merge `develop` into `master`.